# asynchronous reading db returning collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise

I'm tryin to achieve a function which will return *all rooms* of specific user. I'm working with `firebase` and to get a specific room I wrote this function:

```
Db.prototype.getRoom = function (roomUid){

 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + roomUid).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
      resolve(snapshot.val());
    })
 });
}
```

Here is my problem - I need to download all rooms before returning the array. I've tried:

```
Db.prototype.getUserRooms = function(user){

     var rooms = [];

      firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/rooms')
      .once('value').then(function(snapshot){

        var roomsIds = snapshot.val() || []; //array of rooms ids

        for(var i = 0; i < roomsIds.length; i++){
          Db.prototype.getRoom(roomsIds[i]).then(function(room){
            rooms.push(room);
          });
        } 

        return rooms;

      });
 }
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do a couple things to make this work.

First, when you use a `for` loop to retrieve a bunch of async values, you have to collect all the promises and use `Promise.all()` to wait for all those async operations to be done.

Second, when you have a promise inside of a `.then()` handler, you need to return that promise from the `.then()` handler to chain it together.

Third, when you want to call a method from within another method, you need to call it on the instance of your object, not directly on the prototype.

```
// return the inner promise directly rather than wrap in a new promse
Db.prototype.getRoom = function (roomUid){
    return firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + roomUid).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
      // make the `.val()` result be the fulfilled value of the promise
      return snapshot.val();
    })
 });
}

Db.prototype.getUserRooms = function(user){
     var self = this;
     return firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/rooms').once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var roomsIds = snapshot.val() || []; //array of rooms ids
        return Promise.all(roomsIds.map(function(roomID) {
            return self.getRoom(roomID);
        }));
    });
 }
```

Them, I'm still a bit confused why you're calling methods directly on the prototype such as `Db.prototype.getRoom()`.  Usually, when using object oriented Javascript, you would call methods on an instance of the `db` object, not directly on the prototype.  I've modified `getUserRooms()` to work this way, calling `.getRoom()` on the instance.

Then, usage would be like this:

```
 // assumes mydb is an instance of your Db object

mydb.getUserRooms(someUser).then(function(rooms) {
    // rooms is an array of rooms
    console.log(rooms);
});
```